# Как получить email в домене .edu?

Tags: email

Как получить email в домене .edu?

Answer (score 1):

[Не давно была соответствующая статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/hosting/137237/)

Comment: Прочел внимательно, но так и не понял: какова причина получения мыла в данном домене (естественно не обсуждаются противозаконные цели)? Что это даст конечному юзеру?

Comment: Накрутка бесплатного выделенного места в DropBox'е.

Answer (score 0):

почтовый адрес просто так получить не выйдет 
Сначала регим домен в данной зоне (у провайдеров, которые предоставляют данные услуги), покупаем услугу "почтовый домен" и, вуаля, получаем определенное количество адресов в нужной Вам зоне с доменом моя-школа.edu
Почтовые адреса, соответсвенно будут имя-пользователя@моя-школа.edu